# SWT TableViewer listener conflict on Linux machine

Tags: java, linux, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a peculiar problem when running my project in Ubuntu 14.04.
Here is the scenario:

I have a `ViewPart` which containers a `TableViewer`. The TableViewer has a `ISelectionChangedListener` attached to it so that it can track the selection of row in the Table.

There is also a `TableCursor` for the Table of TableViewer and it has two listeners attached: `KeyAdapter` to listen to keyboard buttons and `MenuDetectListener`.

The problem I faced is that when I want select multiple rows in the table with shift key and mouse click, the key listener is triggered but the selection listener does not work. So multiple rows can't be selected

In another case, when I want to right click a row to open menu items, only the selection listener is triggered but the menu detect listener does not activate. Only when I click the same row again, the menu detect listener activates because selection listener does not active.

This leads me to believe that there is a conflict between listeners. However, I observed this only on Linux machine, while it works fine on windows.

I understand that the problem is pretty unique in my case, however I want to know if anyone faced something similar before and if there is a workaround.

SWT Plugin Dependency:`org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.102.1.v20140206-1358.jar`

Comment: Are you running on GTK3? I have read that there are still [open issues with SWT on GTK3](http://www.jroller.com/andyl/entry/mars_on_linux).

Comment: Similar problem here: Focus Events such as focusGained(), focusLost(), SWT.FocusIn, SWT.FocusOut don't work on Linux platform but work on Windows platform...

Comment: GTK Version: 2.24.23
Printed it out from the eclipse  :)

//Print Gtk version.
  System.out.println("GTK Version: " + OS.gtk_major_version() + "."
      + OS.gtk_minor_version() + "." + OS.gtk_micro_version());